# pm-update fails "sh: --backend=2: command not found"

Tags: drush

The pm-download command is working so I can update modules individually, but I can't do it in bulk. Both drush 6.2.0 and 6.1.0 give an error.

The output of `drush up --debug` is the following.

> Bootstrap to phase 0. [0.01 sec, 2.24 MB]
>   [bootstrap] Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drush() [0.01
>   sec, 2.37 MB] [bootstrap] Cache HIT cid:
>   6.2.0-commandfiles-0-da12a99782b48770f5d9ad8965ca5448 [0.02 sec, 2.39 MB]           [debug] Bootstrap to phase 0. [0.09 sec, 6.4 MB]
>   [bootstrap] Bootstrap to phase 6. [0.14 sec, 6.4 MB]
>   [bootstrap] Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_root()
>   [0.14 sec, 6.41 MB]                     [bootstrap] Initialized Drupal
>   7.24 root directory at /path/to/site [0.16 sec, 7.43 MB]    [notice] Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_site() [0.16 sec, 7.44
>   MB]                     [bootstrap] Initialized Drupal site default at
>   sites/default [0.16 sec, 7.44 MB]
>   [notice] Cache HIT cid:
>   6.2.0-install_profile-66ecfeb9791a023150773849f1550c5d [0.16 sec, 7.45 MB]          [debug] Cache HIT cid:
>   6.2.0-commandfiles-2-699657487b88e8b0c2ede2984aa12913 [0.16 sec, 7.45 MB]           [debug] Drush bootstrap phase :
>   _drush_bootstrap_drupal_configuration() [0.17 sec, 7.47 MB]            [bootstrap] Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_database()
>   [0.17 sec, 7.51 MB]                 [bootstrap] Successfully connected
>   to the Drupal database. [0.17 sec, 7.51 MB]
>   [bootstrap] Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_full()
>   [0.18 sec, 8.14 MB]                     [bootstrap] Cache HIT cid:
>   6.2.0-install_profile-66ecfeb9791a023150773849f1550c5d [0.37 sec, 26.15 MB]         [debug] Cache HIT cid: 6.2.0-commandfiles-5-8aee30ce3a469e89d0725cfb79ceb51b [0.37 sec, 26.16 MB]          [debug] Drush bootstrap phase :
>   _drush_bootstrap_drupal_login() [0.38 sec, 26.62 MB]                   [bootstrap] Successfully logged into Drupal as Guest (uid=0) [0.38
>   sec, 26.63 MB]                          [bootstrap] Found command:
>   pm-update (commandfile=pm) [0.38 sec, 26.63 MB]
>   [bootstrap] Calling hook drush_pm_update [0.71 sec, 26.97 MB]
>   [debug] Loading release_info engine. [0.9 sec, 29.07 MB]
>   [notice] Loading version_control engine. [0.9 sec, 29.17 MB]
>   [notice] Loading package_handler engine. [0.91 sec, 29.19 MB]
>   [notice] Executing: wget --version Including
>   /usr/local/Cellar/drush/6.2.0/libexec/commands/pm/updatecode.pm.inc
>   [0.93 sec, 29.21 [bootstrap] MB] Calling hook
>   drush_pm_updatecode_validate [0.94 sec, 29.31 MB]
>   [debug] Returned from hook drush_pm_updatecode_validate [0.94 sec,
>   29.31 MB]                               [debug] Calling hook drush_pm_updatecode [0.94 sec, 29.32 MB]
>   [debug] Cache HIT cid:
>   6.2.0-alias-path--2c8463220c4fed24dfb54242bc0f682e [0.94 sec, 29.36 MB]             [debug] Backend invoke:   --backend=2 --verbose
>   --debug --root=/path/to/site          [command]
>   --uri=site.local  pm-updatestatus 2>&1 [1.26 sec, 29.37 MB]   --backend=2 --verbose --debug --root=/path/to/site --uri=site.local            [notice] pm-updatestatus 2>&1 [1.26 sec, 29.38 MB] Illegal string
>   offset 'site' backend.inc:1013 [1.27 sec, 29.38 MB]
>   [warning] The command could not be executed successfully (returned:
>   sh: --backend=2: command not found   [error] , code: 127) [1.27 sec,
>   29.38 MB] Returned from hook drush_pm_updatecode [1.27 sec, 29.36 MB]                                        [debug] Changes made in drush_pm_updatecode have been rolled back.
>   [1.27 sec, 29.37 MB]                 [rollback] Command dispatch
>   complete [1.27 sec, 29.34 MB]
>   [notice] Returned from hook drush_pm_update [1.28 sec, 27.27 MB]
>   [debug] Command dispatch complete [1.28 sec, 27.24 MB]
>   [notice]  Timer  Cum (sec)  Count  Avg (msec)   page   1.113      1
>   1113.33 Peak memory usage was 31.64 MB [1.28 sec, 27.24 MB]                                               [memory]

The issue happens under OS X Mountain Lion and PHP 5.4.20, and continued after upgrading to Mavericks.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because Drush is trying to find the local Drush executable via `$drush = realpath($_SERVER['argv']['0']);`.  In this context, realpath is returning FALSE, because $_SERVER['argv']['0'] does not exist.

As a workaround for this particular problem (which is that pm-update cannot call updatedb), you could run `drush pm-updatecode` followed by `drush updatedb`.

#### Note

If you work around the problem instead of solving it, you will also run into this same issue with other commands, such as sql-sync.

Comment: This is on a local install, it happens when using an alias or when running from the drupal directory.

Comment: Run the command again with the --debug flag; show the full command you are running, and all of the output. Also, please specify your php and Drupal versions, and what O.S. you are running on.  Drush shouldn't be including --backend=2 unless you are using a site alias with a 'remote-host' entry set, so the results you are seeing are unexpected.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help greg, I added the info to the OP.

Comment: I'm not sure why Drush can't find your executable. You could try to diagnose this via `drush ev 'return $_SERVER["argv"]["0"];'`

Comment: `drush ev 'return $_SERVER["argv"]["0"];'` returns `'/usr/local/Cellar/drush/6.2.0/libexec/drush.php'`

Comment: `drush pm-updatecode` gives the same error as `drush up`: `The command could not be executed successfully (returned: sh: --backend=2: command not found`.

Comment: I don't know; it shouldn't be doing that, and does not behave that way on any system that I've observed.  You're going to have to do more debugging to find out why you are getting different results.

Comment: It's now working again after I set the path to the local drush binary under %drush-script in the aliases. Should that be necessary?

Comment: No, it should not be necessary. If you set %drush-script to an empty string, that might explain the symptoms you are seeing above. Since you've found a workaround, I'd go with it.

Comment: That solved it, I deleted the %drush and %drush-script aliases for my local server from the drushrc.php file. Thanks!

Comment: I ran into this on my local and stopping and then restarting MySQL resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

I used `drush pm-updatecode --debug` from inside the Drupal root and it shows the failure. I think drush can't find out where it is. The first line of the output is this:
    "C:\Users\dj\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\drush\drush\drush"
    --backend=2 --verbose --debug --root="E:\DJs
Documents\public_html\Drupal_80" --uri=http://default

The "default" seems to be the problem.
Also,

```
drush ev 'return $_SERVER['argv']['0']);'
```

returned nothing (no error either).